# Лаги при использовании notifyItemChanged в recyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, recyclerview.adapter

Всем доброго дня суток. Разбираюсь с recyclerView и возник вопрос.
Есть приложение

[image: Скрин]

Есть адаптер для списка

```
public class ItemViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
private Context appContext;

public void setItems(ArrayList<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    appContext=parent.getContext();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items.get(position), position);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView nameItem;
    Button lessCount;
    EditText count;
    Button moreCount;
    TextView price;
    ImageButton addToCart;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        nameItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        lessCount = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.less_count);
        count = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        moreCount = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.more_count);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_textview);
        addToCart = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);

    }

    public void bind(final Item item, final int position){
        nameItem.setText(null);
        nameItem.setText(item.getName());
        count.setText(null);
        count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCount()));
        price.setText(null);
        price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));

        lessCount.setOnClickListener(null);
        lessCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.lessCount();
                price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
                count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCount()));
                //notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
        count.setOnClickListener(null);
        count.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try{
                    item.setCount(Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                    price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
                }
                catch (Exception e){}

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
        moreCount.setOnClickListener(null);
        moreCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item.addCount();//todo цифры странно прыгают
                price.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
                count.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCount()));
                //notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
        addToCart.setOnClickListener(null);
        addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShoppingCartController.get(appContext).addItemToCart(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Если я использую метод notifyItemChanged(он закомментирован в коде) вместо ручных изменений полей count и price, начинаются глюки, например, при клике more/less значения в поле editText временно накладываются друга друга, то есть видно 2,на ней 3 нарисована и тп, или если нажимать кнопки у другого элемента списка, то в editText выводится значение от операции с предыдущим элементом списка(с которым работали до этого). Есть какие то нюансы у notifyItemChanged в моем случае? и насколько правильно(точнее профессионально) использовать setText в лоб в листенерах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

notifyItemChanged вызовет заново вашу функцию bind, и выставит значения в ваших вьюхах соответственно вашему Item (дальше буду звать это моделью). Также у вас есть листенеры на изменения в ваших вьюхах, которые изменяют Вашу модель в соответствии с вьюхами + зависящие от этих изменений вьюхи. Соответственно вы два раза делаете одно и то же (обновляете зависящие вьюхи сначала в листенерах, а потом при биндинге). Я бы посоветовал вам либо выставлять все в листенерах: и модель, и состояния вьюх, тогда вызов notifyItemChanged не нужен. Либо в листенерах вы меняете только модель, а затем вызываете notifyItemChanged и происходит ребинд ваших вьюх. С точки зрения UX, как по мне, красивее и интереснее будет первый вариант, т.к. изменения происходят в отдельных полях без обновления целиком холдера. Во втором случае будет видно как обновился весь холдер целиком, а не какое-то конкретное поле. Конечно выбор зависит от целей и того как вы хотите это преподнести юзеру.

P.S. Еще у вас при клике на moreCount/lessCount выставляется text у count, при этом сработает textChangeListener и выполнится дважды одна и та же работа по выставлению price и item.count